# how do i ensure that a service is running even if the phone is on standby?

Tags: android

I have a service that spawns a thread which runs a task every 3 seconds.

```
class MyService extends Service {
  private Timer timer = new Timer();

  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
        // something important
      }
    };

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 3000);
    return Service.START_STICKY;
  }
  ...
}
```

My service runs fine when my phone is on, but when my phone is on standby, the service is often not responding.

Any clues as to how I can ensure my service is running while on standby?

Comment: Running something every three seconds, even while the phone is asleep, says you hate your users, or at least hate their batteries. Your users will likely respond by hating your app, killing it off and giving you one-star ratings on the Market. Please make this configurable and much longer (e.g., every 15 minutes). Using `AlarmManager`, as fuhcho recommends, is then a fine strategy. See more here: http://www.androidguys.com/2010/03/29/code-pollution-background-control/

Comment: @commonsware, unfortunately, my service can't wait for 15 minute intervals.  android 2.1 doesn't support push via Android Cloud to Device messaging yet, so I have to poll manually, which is why I run the task every 5 seconds. I'm open to any other suggestions you may have.

Comment: " I'm open to any other suggestions you may have" -- 1. Don't write the app 2. Use SMS-based push 3. Require 2.2 and try C2DM (note, officially in beta) 4. Use Urban Airship or other third-party C2DM-style engines 5. See if somebody else has cooked up a WebSocket or Comet-style long-poll that allows the CPU to fall back asleep on Android (which is possible, as incoming data packets on a 3G-based open socket apparently serves as a CPU-wakeup trigger, which is why VOIP apps can work) 6. Give the user control anyway, per my original comment, since it is their phone, not yours.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use alarms via `AlarmManager` class.